# How to install linux (BackBox) and windows on the same computer?

Tags: linux, dual-boot

I have a Dell 1564. I want to install back-box a Debian based flavor of Linux.

I don't really wish to dual boot like switching between operating systems, but I do wish to run either at choice from the hard drive. Can I partition the hard drives in two parts and install Linux on one and windows 7 on the other?

If so will, I get a choice when booting?

Comment: What you describe (getting a choice when booting) is exactly what dual-boot (or triple-boot, or...) is.

Comment: Related: http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/76932/installing-debian-7-besides-windows-8

Answer (score 0):

So you want to dual boot on a single hard drive without using a boot manager like grub?
You simply can't.

However, most laptops and computers will run from a USB key, external harddisk (eSATA or USB) or SD Card.

And Linux - depending on your use - will run easily on anything up from 8GB

I've had good experience with a high grade 32 GB and 16 GB SD Cards.
Simply connect the card, stick or drive and you'll be able to boot from the disk selection menu.